# ¿Se pueden distinguir las patatas fritas en español?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario

Recuerdo que que de pequeño mi madre me preguntaba `¿Vas a querer patatas fritas?` y yo a veces me llevaba una desilusión, porque respondía que sí, pero quería patatas fritas *de las otras*. A veces me preguntaba,

> ¿Las quieres **de bolsa**?

Y con eso me daba a entender que eran de "las industriales". Vamos, también las podrías comprar en la churrería, pero no eran las típicas que hacías en casa. Los americanos distinguen entre *french fries* y *chips*. Para los británicos *chips* son lo que los americanos llaman *french fries* y las otras son *crisp*. Parece ser que los australianos les llaman *chips* a las dos, de la misma manera que nosotros, que no tenemos [forma de distinguirlas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU2lS.jpg), ¿o sí?

¿Se pueden distinguir en español ambos tipos de patatas fritas?

Comment: Creo que lo más usado es lo que tú mencionas, "de bolsa". En la Wikipedia mencionan "papas fritas inglesas" (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papas_fritas_inglesas#Denominaciones) pero yo nunca lo escuché en todos mis años de consumo : )

Comment: @fedorqui Toda la razón. La típica conversación sobre esto sería _El otro día nos comimos unas patatas fritas que estaban buenísimas._ _De bolsa o *de las otras?*_

Comment: Sé que hay gente que usa o reconoce "chips" para llamar a las de bolsa, pero no sé cómo de extendido está. Por otro lado, cuando estuve en Inglaterra, algunos distinguían entre *french fries* (más finas y crujientes, como en McDonald's y similares) y *chips* (más gruesas)...

Comment: @fedorqui conviértelo en respuesta. Es que lo es.

Answer (score 5):

Curiosa pregunta y habría que agregar una etiqueta para indicar que depende de la región.

Toda mi vida he estado acostumbrado a "un paquete de papas/papitas" para hacer referencia a las industriales. Que pueden venir en tajadas (chip) o en fosforito (palitos muy delgados).

Las caseras simplemente son papitas fritas, que pueden ser: a la francesa ( cortes largos y gruesos), tajada (chip) o fosforito. Hay otras papas que son pequeñas, papas criollas, que se fríen/ cocinan y se comen enteras (papitas criollas)

Respecto a como referirse para comprar papas crudas, es por unidad de peso (2 kilos de papa, una libra de papa criolla, etc)

Nota: de Antioquia, Colombia

Answer (score 2):

La verdad es que no conozco otra forma de nombrarlas, aunque aquí en Sonora nadie le dice *papas fritas* a las que vienen en bolsa.

Simplemente son *las papitas* (las de bolsa) o *papas* y las *papas fritas* son las french fries.

Comment: Entonces a la patata (o papa) frita de bolsa o inglesa se le llama igual que a la patata cruda? Si la madre le dice al niño que vaya a la compra a por "una bolsa de patatas" el niño no sabe si son patatas fritas/papitas (Matutano, Lays, Pringles, lo que sea) o patatas "crudas" para hacer un guiso? Es decir, mismo problema de desambiguación, simplemente entre dos cosas distintas.